# Docker + HHVM: CMD fails but same command on CL works

Tags: docker, hhvm

I'm playing around with HHVM, and I'm running into an issue when trying to run my Dockerized HHVM container: whenever I try to pass CL arguments to HHVM, it fails when used from the Dockerfile CMD, but that very same command works when I add it as an argument on 'docker run'.

Here's my Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:jessie

# install HHVM
RUN apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0x5a16e7281be7a449 && \
    echo deb http://dl.hhvm.com/debian jessie main | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hhvm.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install hhvm

VOLUME ["/var/www/html"]

# simply phpinfo();
COPY index.php /var/www/html/index.php

EXPOSE 9000

ENTRYPOINT ["hhvm"]

CMD ["-m s -v Server.Type=fastcgi -v Server.Port=9000"]
```

Whenever I try to run this container `docker run -d me/hhvm` I get `Error in command line: invalid mode: s -v Server.Type=fastcgi -v Server.Port=9000`.

I've also tried the following:

- Without spaces between `-v` and `Server.x`. Same error as above.
- With `--mode server` (which is how the official docs say to use) and I get the error `unrecognised [sic] option '--mode server -vSer...` etc.

However, with the Dockerfile as configured above, I can run the following command and it works as expected. `docker run -d me/hhvm -m s -v Server.Type=fastcgi -v Server.Port=9000`.

No errors, the container is running and accepts connections through port 9000, etc.

So what am I missing?